# How to tell when windows users have switched

Tags: vb.net

So i am trying to add some windows 7+ functionality to a VB.NET application where i need to be able to tell the following

a) When the active user switches to a different user (using the switch user functionality in Windows 7) ideally looking to trigger some kind of event within my application when this happens.

b) the username of the current active user compared to the user who is running my application

I have so far not found a simple way of doing this (especailly 'a') so would be grateful if someone could share any knowledge they may have on this subject.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What kind of application is it?  If it has a UI, then it won't be running in the new user's session.  The new user would have to run their own instance of your application.  If it's a windows service, on the other hand...

Comment: @roryap Yes its a large multi functional application with a UI (dificult to explain everything it does)... its definitely not a widows service.

Comment: Like I said, it won't be running in the new user's UI when you switch users.  Windows doesn't work like that.

Comment: So if i get what you are saying, you cant do the following: user 1 has my application running and leaves the machine to go on a break. User 2 comes along and logs himself into the machine by switching user which triggers an event in my application running on User 1's session???

Comment: Sure that's possible. Have you considered using inter process communication?

Comment: If i'd have heard of that before you just mentioned it i probably would have considered it.... but i haven't so i'll have a google. Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).